# Recover min values to apply a transformation in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have divided a dataset between a training and a test set. On the training set I apply a normalization using the minimum and maximum values of this dataset. Let's use the iris dataset as an example:

```
iris_vars <- iris[,1:4] %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())
iris_train <- iris_vars %>%
  sample_n(100)

iris_test <- iris_vars %>%
  filter(!id %in% iris_train$id)

iris_train_norm <- iris_train %>% 
  select(-id) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
                .fns = function(x) (x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))))

head(iris_train_norm)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1    0.9444444   0.3333333   0.96610169  0.79166667
2    0.1666667   0.4583333   0.08474576  0.00000000
3    0.9444444   0.2500000   1.00000000  0.91666667
4    0.2777778   0.7083333   0.08474576  0.04166667
5    0.2222222   0.2083333   0.33898305  0.41666667
6    0.2222222   0.7500000   0.08474576  0.08333333
```

Now to apply this transformation on the test set I have to remember the min values of the train set. This is a way to get the min and max values on the train set as vectors:

```
iris_train_mins <- c(min(iris_train$Sepal.Length),
                     min(iris_train$Sepal.Width),
                     min(iris_train$Petal.Length),
                     min(iris_train$Petal.Width))
> iris_train_mins
[1] 4.3 2.0 1.0 0.1

iris_train_maxs <- c(max(iris_train$Sepal.Length),
                     max(iris_train$Sepal.Width),
                     max(iris_train$Petal.Length),
                     max(iris_train$Petal.Width))

> iris_train_maxs
[1] 7.9 4.4 6.9 2.5
```

Now I have to use these vectors maxs and mins. Since the denominator is fixed, my problem is with the subtraction of the min for each row. I tried this with sweep:

These are the first two observations of the test set:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
```

subtracting the min

```
[1] 4.3 2.0 1.0 0.1
```

Should be:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
0.3          1.4         0.4          0.2
0.1          0.9         0.4          0.1
```

But I apply sweep and I get a wrong answer:

```
first_step <- sweep(iris_test[,1:4], 1, iris_train_mins, FUN = "-")
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1           0.3         2.4         -2.9        -0.7
2           2.4         2.8         -0.6         0.1
```

Please, do you know what I am doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use `sweep` across margin 2. Try `first_step <- sweep(iris_test[,1:4], 2, iris_train_mins, FUN = "-")` You should have got some warning in the console while running this with margin 1.

Comment: I completely missed that. Thank you @RonakShah. How can I award the points of this question to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To subtract the data column-wise by the minimum you need to use `sweep` with margin 2. Try -

```
cols <- 1:4
first_step <- sweep(iris_test[cols], 2, sapply(iris_train[cols], min), `-`)
first_step
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ronak Shah, by the way the method to get the mins helped me too!

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- iris_test %>% 
     mutate(across(1:4, ~ . - min(iris_train[[cur_column()]])))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun for the answer, interesting approach!